# Question about Psalm 2 (You are my Son, today I have begotten you)

Tags: christology, hebrews, david, psalms, divinity

Christians have understood Psalm 2:7 as a reference to Jesus as the begotten Son of God. But how could this be if Psalm 2 is God speaking to the King of Israel? The response is typically that this verse refers to the Messiah *as well* as the King. But there are two questions that come to mind in regard to this answer:

1. How can this text be used to show that is Jesus unique in his sonship if it also applies to the King?
2. Hebrews 1:5 applies Psalm 2 to Jesus in order to establish Jesus' superiority over the angels. But wouldn't this also prove the King's superiority over the angels as well?

Comment: Can you rephrase this question - I am not sure I understand what you think the problem is. King of Israel = Messiah = Son of God. John 1:49 "“Rabbi,” Nathanael answered, “You are the Son of God! You are the King of Israel!” ?

Comment: Peter states this text in the context of the resurrection of Jesus, it should be noted. _God hath fulfilled the same unto us their children, in that he hath raised up Jesus again; as it is also written in the second psalm, Thou art my Son, this day have I begotten thee._ Acts 13:33.

Comment: This is an academic site. Let us keep the comments at a polite and academic level please.